# Is asynchronous embed code swap with Python and Selenium/Selenium-wire possible?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, adobe-analytics, seleniumwire

I'm trying to programmatically replace an Adobe Experience Platform tag embed code in the head of a website loaded in my browser. I can do this manually via the Adobe Experience Platform Debugger browser extension, but I need to do this automatically for automated testing.

This is in the head of the webpage (unique data replaced with ellipsis):

```
<script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/.../launch-....min.js" async></script>
```

I want to be able to change the source to a different URL. Is that even possible? Would a request interceptor work?

Comment: I think this is possible with a request interceptor, but seems like you'd need to supply the entire response.  (there's probably an easier way to achieve what you want... maybe  by overriding the types/methods after the page loads...)  What's the purpose of changing the src?

Comment: @pcalkins The purpose is to test different tag manager environments. I'm testing our analytics and we want to know if certain events are being triggered under the new tag manager environment before it goes live.

Comment: probably best to use a staging or development server with the proper tags already embedded.